# How to make a picturebox in a form visible by referencing a method from another class

Tags: c#, forms, class, methods, picturebox

my image "Input1GreenLight" needs to be visible when my FormCall thread method is called. However, in my "while (true)" infinite loop, I call the class Form1.setLights(), which calls the method in the Form1.cs, but I can not access Input1GreenLight as it says "this member can not be reference from a static context".

So I realize the issue, but I'm not sure how to fix/address it, suggestions appreciated and please find code snippets below (please keep in mind, FormCall is being called through a new thread, and thus is not blocking my program). Also, do not mind GlobalVars.Input1, that is being used by a separate piece of code.

Code from my C# Script

```
public static void FormCall()
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Form1());
  while (true)
    {
      Form1.setLights();
    }
}
```

Code from my Form1 Script

```
public static void setLights()
 {
    Input1GreenLight.Visible = GlobalVars.Input1;
 }
```

Input1GreenLight is the picturebox's name, just to clarify again. I am new to C#, familiar with C/C++. Thank you in advance

Comment: Picturebox won't be accessible until you create an instance of `Form1`. Using infinite loop for the purpose of controls visibility is not good choice. You could make the `Modifiers` property of every control as `Public` and use the same instance of `Form1` within other class.

Comment: Hi Hassan, thanks for your feedback. Could you please elaborate on your suggestion, I understand making an instance of Form1, what do you mean in regards to the modifiers property?

Comment: Please check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233630(v=vs.110).aspx). When you set the `Modifiers` property of a control to `Public`, it would be accessible from other classes. When you will pass the form1 object to other class. It should show all public members. Example: `objForm1.Input1GreenLight`, provided you have set Modifiers property. **NOTE**: You could expose custom public property as well.

Comment: Ok thank you very much Hassan, I will review the link, and try it out. I understand the risks, but this is a small issue that could temporarily resolve a much bigger issue until i learn the language better to better modify. Thank you for your support. Salam

Comment: Wsalaam, you are welcome :)

Comment: Let's get the terminology right, folks: You neither need an 'instance' of Form1 nor would it help. You need a __reference__ to the original form1 or to the control(s) you want to manipulate or to a method that does the work..